# Derivation of Air resistance using Conservation Of Energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

I have been asked to derive an expression for the air resistance that a car moving with a constant velocity faces. The variables are mass of car, velocity of car, mass of air, density of air, cross sectional area of car. We can assume the car as a simple cylinder. The hint is that the car 'moves out' a mass of air, with the same speed that it moves forward and we can get an idea of the kinetic energy that's transferred in the exchange. Can someone please help me in solving this?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_coefficient).